# Dynamic xAxis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a char and I want to display some text on the xAxis Categories, I'll create xAxis array dynamically, every label must be with a tickInterval of 5, I can do this with numbers but I don't know how to do it with text, here if my chart:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#xd').click(function () {
    draw();
  });
});

function draw() {
  var myArray = [];
  myArray = [1, 5, 10, 11, 8, 6, 7 ,8 ,9, 10];
  var dates = [];
  dates = ["11/Nov/16", "11/Dic/16"];
  
  $('#grafic').highcharts({
        
        title: {
            text: 'Sampled Parts'
        },
        xAxis: {
          tickInterval:5,
            categories: dates,
            labels: {
                rotation: -33,
            },
          
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Resultados'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'My Data',
            data: myArray
        }]
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="grafic">
</div>

<button id="xd">Click</button>
```

In other words I want to display `11/Dic/16 instead of 5` how can I do that?

PD. This should work if then I add another 5 values to `myArray` and another date to `dates`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second category name has value 1, so it would appear under the second tick. If you want to use categories, then you have to fill it with some values.

```
dates = ["11/Nov/16", '', '', '', '', "11/Dic/16"];
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ty7qs88y/

I think a better way is not using categories array, but a linear axis and in the label formatter invoke the dates array directly.

```
 xAxis: {
      tickInterval:5,
        type: 'linear',

        labels: {
            rotation: -33,
            formatter: function () {
                return dates[this.value / 5];
            }
        },

    },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ty7qs88y/1/

If you use datetime values - you can always use datetime axis and then just format how it is displayed. See [API Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)